# Magento registry variables in controller

Tags: magento

I have stored a variable in register by `Mage::register('captcha', $var);` in **helper**. And in the **controller** i tried to retrieve the variable by using `Mage::registry('captcha');`  But i dont getting any values here. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: In your helper try fetching the value of `$var` and make sure its not empty

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I got the value in helper. But in my module i need the value in controller. I have written a method in helper to retrieve the registry variable and i call this method from controller, still i couldnt get anything

Comment: Pls paste the helper function you called for to retireve registry variable

Comment: Mage::helper('myhelper')->getCaptcha(); In getCaptcha, i have return Mage::registry('captcha'); previously i have set the registry variable by using Mage::register('captcha', $sum);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your helper file create a function like below :

```
public function getCaptcha(){
    $var = 'myValue123';
    Mage::register('varun', $var);
    return Mage::registry('varun');
}
```

In your controller function:

```
$registryValue = Mage::helper('yourModule')->getCaptcha();
echo registryValue ; //prints myValue123
```

Hope it helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

It's look like syntax is right.
Please first try to set some static value like `$var="test"`

```
Mage::register('captcha', $var);
```

after that got this value in `controller`.

```
Mage::registry('captcha');
```

if you got this value test then i think you have problem with `$var` in your `helper`.

Let me know if you have any problem

Comment: No, I tried with both static and dynamic values. But still the same.

Answer (score 0):

'captcha' is already in use, so magento never set your data in registry. Change the name, for example 'captcha1'

```
Mage::register('captcha1', $var);
```